# Using terminal on Mac OS X to connect to Windows Machine

Tags: windows, networking, macos, ssh, terminal

've done some research on google and it seems I might be asking the wrong question that would yield minor results. So I hope someone could shed some light on my confusion.

Ideally, I connect using SSH with mac to mac and of course, mac has a build-in SSH software. However, it seems that Windows doesn't have SSH natively built-in.

Here are a few questions I have, as follows...

1.) How would a Mac user (like myself) connect to a Windows Machine using terminal without installing any additional software on both machines?

2.) If I have to set up a few settings on the Windows machine to activate the SSH/Telnet services, is there a way to build a Windows Script (I believe it's a batch.bat executable file?) that would do this in the background, similar to creating a Shell Script (.sh) file on a Mac?

From what I hear, Telnet is pretty much not the popular choice.

Thanks for any input on this subject.

Comment: There is a pretty good `sshd` install guide here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server.  You'd need to wrap up the commands in a BAT or PowerShell script, but it's definitely do-able.

Comment: BAT as in a windows script? Is there a way to run the script as an executable using .exe extension? Something similar to Mac OS (**PlatyPus**). Is there anyway I can PM you about this if you're willing to help further?

Comment: Keep discussions on SO public so others can benefit too. I've used Platypus a lot too, but haven't heard of a Windows equivalent. BAT is just as effective as EXE on Windows, although of course that means others can read the script. Not good if you need to put a password in there, but otherwise it's good in that people can see what the script is doing and know they can trust it.